# Error comes when i call objects from another class i.e. "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, class, object, methods

my program gives error when i try to compile it. I don't know whats wrong. Please help me. It gives error in 21st and 22nd line. 
Code is

```
class Rectangle {

    int length;
    int breadth;

    void setdata(int x, int y) {
        length = x;
        breadth = y;
    }

    int Area() {
        int rectarea = length * breadth;
        return rectarea;
    }
};

class Calculate {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Cal obj = new Cal();
        obj.setdata(3, 4);
        int result = obj.Area();
        System.out.println("Result is " + result);

    }
};
```

It gives error in `obj.setdata(3,4);` and `int result=obj.Area();`. Please help me and tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: you should paste the content of new Cal(); We dont know what class Cal have And btw add the error stacktrace

Comment: can you please tell me more specifically and elaborate it ....and thanks for telling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your class is `Rectangle` and not `Cal` so replace this piece :

```
Cal obj=new Cal();
```

By:

```
Rectangle obj = new Rectangle();
```

Note

It is not require to set `;` after `}` like you do in the end of your classes `};`.

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thankyou so much @YCF_L .It worked, earlier i thought i was creating a object in Calculate class and i have to make its obejct. 

Now i get it...


just clarify me a little more....am i wrong or not..

We have to make objects of the class whose objects we want to call.